# Using html input type month to show the value of year and month in Django

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have an input type month where I ask a user to type the start_month and start_year for a job. However, the field month is optional. Like a user can only specify the start year. In my model, I store start_month as a CharField with values like 'January', 'February'. I store start_year as an IntegerField. I already have the values stored and I have even successfully retrieved them such that they show up in the template if i do {{ job.start_month }}

The issue is how do I display that by the value attribute in the input type month provided that a user can have only year and month or year?

Please help :(((
Note: I am not comfortable with Django forms :/

Here is my code snippet:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="start">From:</label>
    <input style="margin-left: 5px;" type="month" class="start_date" value=" 
    {% if job.start_year and job.start_month %}{{ job.start_year }}-{{ 
    job.start_month_as_number }}{% else %} {{ job.start_year }}-{% endif %}" 
    name="start">
</div>
```

Comment: Show your models

Comment: @Sumithran I edited my code. Is there a way I make the month name become a number? Like January becomes 01? This solution works for one scenario if I hardcode the month number

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Model:

```
@property
def start_month_as_number(self):
    if not self.start_month:
        return ""
    month_dict = {
        "January":"01",
        "February":"02",
        "March":"03",
        "April":"04",
        "May":"05",
        "June":"06",
        "July":"07",
        "August":"08",
        "September":"09",
        "October":"10",
        "November":"11",
        "December":"12",        
    }
        return month_dict[self.start_month]
```

Then in your template you can print it like this: `{{job.start_month_as_number}}`

You also need to add the choices parameter to your `start_month` field for safety.

```
month_choices = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August",September"","October", "November", "December"]

class StudentWorkExperience(models.Model):
...
    start_month = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=month_choices, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: @E Paul, what is this line doing {{job.start_month_as_number}}? Generally, I know that the start_month can be accessed by job.start_month

Comment: @E Paul, would be glad if u can quickly walk me through it

Comment: It's converting the month's name to a number. As you need it.

Comment: @E Paul okayy. N what about the scenario when I don't have a month but only a year? Sorry im bothering you

Comment: It will return an empty string and no month will be shown. I don't quite understand what are you trying to do.

Comment: @E Paul, Im getting this error "January":01,
               ^
SyntaxError: leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted; use an 0o prefix for octal integers