# How to save a form which contains a container div with sub-divs that have been dynamically added in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am working on a job portal system. I provide users the chance to edit their profiles by adding and removing job experiences. The issue is I don't know how to send that data to the view so that it can retrieve all the fields and store them in the database accordingly. By retrieving, I mean for each job experience, retrieve their corresponding sub fields

Here is my template file:

```
<!--JOB EXPERIENCE-->

        <div class="job_experience">
            <h5>Experience</h5>
            <hr>

            <!--FORM-->
            <form action="#" id="save_job_experience_form" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="job_container">
                {% for job in job_experience %}
                <div class="exp">
        
                 <label>Organisation</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="organisation 
                 placeholder="Organisation" value="{% if job.organisation %} 
                 {{job.organisation}}{% endif %}" required>
     
        
                 <label>Job Title</label>
                 <input type="text" name="job_title" class="form-control" value="{% if job.job_title 
                  %}{{ job.job_title }}{% endif %}" placeholder="Job Title e.g Backend Developer" 
                 required>
                      
                
                <button style="margin-left:15px;" type="button" class="btn btn-danger 
                remove_job_exp"><strong>Delete Job Experience</strong></button>
            </div>
            <hr>
           {% endfor %}
               
        </div>
                <!--BUTTONS-->
                <input type="submit"value="Save">
                <input type="button"  id="add_job_experience"value="Add one">
            
            </form>
        </div>

  <script>
        $(document).on('click', '#add_job_experience',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(".job_container").append(`<div class="exp">
                <!--IT GOES ON AS ABOVE -->

        $(document).on('click', 'button.remove_job_exp', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).closest('div.exp').remove();
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can post multiple inputs with the same name like so:

```
<input type="text" name="job[]" value="job1"/>
<input type="text" name="org[]" value="org1"/>
<input type="text" name="job[]" value="job2"/>
<input type="text" name="org[]" value="org2"/>
```

Then in django you can parse the `POST` data like so:

```
@require_POST #require POST method or check if request method is POST
def add_jobs(request):
    jobs = request.POST.getlist('job[]')
    orgs = request.POST.getlist('org[]')
    ...
```

Or use Django Formsets: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: @E Paul, basically i just need to add the square brackets to the names? n then process them in the view?

Comment: Yes, and use request.POST.getlist instead of request.POST.get

Comment: @ E Paul, that's a slick way of doing it ! ^_^ Thank youuu

Comment: Or you can just use Formsets, I updated my answer.

Comment: @ E Paul, Im not so comfy with forms yet. Prefer doing it this way xD

Comment: @ E Paul, if it is right for me to ask, can you have a look at this issue please ? :/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67675137/using-html-input-type-month-to-show-the-value-of-year-and-month-in-django